# `kubctl get pods` has high latency

Tags: kubernetes

I am attempting to identify and fix the source of high latency when running `kubectl get pods`.

I am running `1.1.4` on AWS.

When running the command from the master host of afflicted master, I consistently get response times of 6s.

Other queries, such as `get svc` and `get rc` return on the order of 20ms.

Running `get pods` on a mirror cluster returns in 150ms.

I've crawled through master logs and system stats, but have not identified the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We [speeded up LIST operations](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15945) in `1.2`. You might be interested in learning the [updates to Kubernetes performance and scalability in 1.2](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/1000-nodes-and-beyond-updates-to-Kubernetes-performance-and-scalability-in-12.html).

Comment: Good to know. However I have several clusters of the same size and version (1.1.4), and the performance is only an issue on the one.

Answer (score 0):

Chris - how big cluster do you have and how many pods do you have in it?
Obviously the time it take to return the response will be bigger if the result is bigger.

Also, what do you mean by "running on mirror cluster returns in 150ms"? What is "mirror cluster"?

Comment: 4 nodes, around 40 pods.
By mirror cluster, I me a near identical copy. I.e. same node and pod count - redundant site. 
So I have two clusters of relatively small size, but one could be slightly misconfigured...

Comment: OK  - so 4 nodes and 40 pods are basically nothing - it definitely shouldn't take 6s to list them, not matter which release we are using.
150ms sound more reasonable.

How do you run your clusters? Are them on GCE, AWS, bare metal?
Also, did you started both of them in exactly the same way?
Maybe the worse one is in some distant location?

Comment: Both clusters running in AWS with `kube-up.sh`.
Location shouldn't be a factor - all timings shown from running `kubectl` on master itself.

Comment: Got it - thanks for replying.
To be honest, I have no idea what is happening there. Maybe looking into logs would help.
Can you please check you kube-apiserver.log file for entries like:
Trace "List /api/v1/pods"
(or sth like that maybe with namespace in path, or some suffix in path).

This should give us more information where the bottleneck actually is.